# How to compare parameters in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have list of ID's from a database and pass them in a request to a servlet, but i can't compare them to any number.

I think maybe i have to convert them to integer type:

```
    <c:forEach items="${subjec.id}" var="x">
${x}
  </c:forEach>
<c:forEach items="${listPage}" var = "list">
${list.id} 
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${list.id} == 1">

</c:when>
</c:choose>

</c:forEach>
<c:if test="${subject1.id == 1}"> 
${subject1.id}
</c:if>
```

However, I cant test based on Integer format. Any suggetions for this case?

Comment: your question isn't clear, what you want to compare exactly ?

Answer (score 7):

```
<c:when test="${list.id} == 1">
```

This is wrong. You need to put the *entire* expression inside `${}`.

If `getId()` returns a [`Number`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) (integer, long, etc), then use the following:

```
<c:when test="${list.id == 1}">
```

Or if it returns a [`String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) (which is unnatural by the way), then use the following:

```
<c:when test="${list.id == '1'}">
```

Or if it returns a `boolean` (just as an example), then use the following:

```
<c:when test="${list.id}">
```

Answer (score 2):

it should be `<c:when test="${list.id == '1'}">`
if you use `<c:when test='${list.id == "1"}'>` exception will be thrown

Answer (score -1):

try

```
<c:when test='${list.id == "1"}'>
```